# Undefined reference to statically declared variable in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt

I'm trying to use a static variable so I can call it and set it from multiple class scopes.

Here's my definition:

```
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

    static QString webSite;

private slots:
     void on_actionNew_Site_triggered();
}
```

Here's where I set it:

```
void MainWindow::on_actionNew_Site_triggered()
{
    webSite = QFileDialog::getExistingDirectory(this,tr("Choose Directory"),"");
}
```

I get this error: `error: undefined reference to 'MainWindow::webSite'`

I've tried a few variations and nothing has shown to work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is not enough to declare a `static` variable as a member of a class, you need to define it as well. To do that, put this into your cpp file:

```
QString MainWindow::webSite;
```

Note the absence of `static` in the definition. Once this line is in, the linker will in what object file to put the definition of that `static` variable.

Comment: That gives me `error: invalid use of qualified-name 'MainWindow::webSite' QString MainWindow::webSite;`

Comment: @JVE999 It shouldn't give you that error to you. Check that there's a semicolon after the declaration of the class (it's not there in your post), and make sure that the CPP file includes the header. Here is a quick [demo](http://ideone.com/f8nsRM) of the declare/define concept on ideone.

Comment: This post explained the most recent error: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15169169/c-error-invalid-use-of-qualified-name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15169169/c-error-invalid-use-of-qualified-name) It was because I placed `QString MainWindow::webSite;` in a function. After fixing that, everything works now.

Comment: @JVE999 You didn't put the definition inside a function, did you?

Comment: Yeah, that's what I did.